# Trigger automation if certain merge fields are completed?

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm looking to trigger an automation if the user enters additional information about themselves (i.e. `Date of Birth` and `State`).

Is it possible to trigger an automation if the user adds these details and updates in the Preference Centre?

Mailchimp only allows a trigger on a specific merge field value whereas I want to trigger an automation for `Merge Field Value = NOT EMPTY`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an ideal solution but just a trick that I used to get around it.

You can add an additional field called 'StateAvailable' or 'DOBAvailable' or something else on those lines and then set up your list import such that this field is set to TRUE/FALSE after updating. You can then use this as a trigger for your campaign.